# Is "Do as you please" a complex sentence?

Tags: complex-sentences, independent-clauses

My textbook says that "Do" is an independent clause, which makes "do as you please" an independent clause + a dependent clause. How is "do" an independent clause?

Comment: @All. **Do not discuss in comments.** If you have what you think is a valid point of view, **write it as an answer.**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141480/discussion-on-question-by-annie-is-do-as-you-please-a-complex-sentence).

Answer (score 2):

*Do as you please* is an idiomatic fixed phrase, and as such it isn't parsed as **any** kind of sentence by some people -- it's just a phrase like *Fine, thanks* or *How bout those Bears*, meaning nothing and just meeting social norms for interaction.

That's for **some** people. Other people regard them grammatically, and there -- since it's idiomatic for some -- the syntactic parses of various speakers may well not align well. I can think of a number of possibilities

- *as* is a small word and prepositions are small words, so some folks will probly take *as you please* for a prepositional phrase, with a manner adverb sense, especially since there are idiomatic phrases like *as a rule* to model this analysis after
- *as* is also very similar to (and may be semantically related to) *is*, an auxiliary verb. Coming right after another auxiliary verb *do* and right before a pronoun *you*, some folks might figure it was some kind of complex verb phrase axiom like *do as you would be done by*, with a weird verb construction.
- and of course there is always the reductionist derivation, from

  - *(You) do [(that which) you please (to do)]*
    with the first and last optional parenthesized bits deleted,
    and the middle parenthesized *that which* compressed into *what* or *as*

  > Note that the *please* of the last case is the experiencer-subject *please*
  > of *if you please*, not the flip *please* of *if it pleases you*.

The third case has a main clause and a subordinate clause, so that makes it a complex sentence. For the people who parse it that way, at least. Others will never know that it's complex.

Answer (score 0):

"Do" is a complete sentence, in the imperative.  Therefore, there is an implied [You] as the subject.

"[You] do" is the independent clause.

Answer (score 0):

> How is "do" an independent clause?

I can't seem to think of a context where "do" alone can ever be an independent clause, because the verb is a head that always requires a dependent, be it a complement (including an object) or an adjunct.

In "do as you please", I think "as you please" is the complement of the verb. Some might argue that it's rather the adjunct of the verb. But regardless, it certainly is the dependent of the head verb "do". Therefore, the independent clause is not "do" alone but the entire "do as you please".

In conclusion, the author of your textbook has no clue as to what an independent clause is.

Comment: "Do." can be a standalone sentence, although "Please do." might be more common.

Comment: @StuartF Yes, you're right. But that "do" with or without "please" is an auxiliary whereas OP's "do" is not, so...